# Design Pattern to be followed for the scenario below

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have three different types of setups(a class corresponding to each). Consider, that we know the setup that has to be followed (say out of **1, 2 and 3**). Now, each setup requires different settings.

1. Suppose, we have **SettingB, SettingC, SettingD** that is common to all the three setups except **SettingA**. So, what I did was, I have a common interface Settings for all the settings type(A, B and C).

   ```
   interface IConfigureSettings
   {
     void ConfigureSettings();
   }
   ```

   Only this method will be exposed for each setting type to configure for each setup.
2. Within SettingA, we have sub settings(**SubSettingsAA, SubSettingsAB, SubSettingsAC**).
   So for this, I have an abstract class for SettingA which is inherited by SubSettingAA, SubSettingAB, SubSettingAC.

   ```
   abstract class SettingA : IConfigureSettings
   {
     List<SettingA> _subSettings;
     public void ConfigureSettings()
     {
           //Should Perform configuration for the given site. This is what I need.
     }
   }
   ```
3. Out of these sub settings both **SubSettingsAA and SubSettingsAB may have 2 different configurations**(say **configurationA(), ConfigurationB()**). ConfigurationA() is not in SubSettingsA. SubSettingsAB class contains both ConfiugrationA() and ConfigurationB().

   ```
   class SubSettingsAA :  SettingA
   {
     ConfigurationB();
   }

   class SubSettingsAB :  SettingA
   {
     ConfigurationA();
     ConfigurationB();
   }

   class SubSettingAC : SettingA
   {
     ConfigurationC();
     ConfigurationD();
   }
   ```

Now, in case of Setup1 only ConfigurationA() is visible , whereas in case of setup2 and setup3 everything is to be configured. Configuration's() in SubSettingAC is to be configured for all the three setups.

So, this is what I have. Now, what I want is to just call ConfigureSettings() for SettingA and it should configure everything based on the setup type. Consider, setup type is available.

Comment: Modified the question a little. Added one more scenario for SubSettings. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to suggest a design. Without knowing more about those classes, we don't know to what extent polymorphism or generics will be appropriate or what supporting patterns might be useful. There's also quite a blizzard of information which it's hard for us to process. I understand that's part of the nature of the question, but it'd probably be better for you to try to nail down some more specific questions and focus on those, along with some minimal code (or even just interface specifications)

Comment: Is this better? Let me know if you have any more doubts with this. Let me know if I need to change the existing class structures or anything else. I need to know what should I do in the ConfigureSettings() for SettingA to achieve the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: Yes, much better! One thing, what are you trying to indicate with the third code snippet? Is, e.g., `ConfigurationB();` a method on class `SubSettingsAA`?

Comment: Yes consider ConfigurationB() is a method in class SubSettingsAA.. Sorry for inappropriate function names

Comment: Okay. So maybe I don't quite understand what a configuration is. Could you give an example of what is actually being done when you call a method like `ConfigurationA()`?

Comment: I have 3 different setups. So, based on that I may need different server settings. Now, each subsettings have more subsubSettings that are grouped as Configurations. That is what ConfigurationA(). ConfigurationB() and so on represents. Now the grouping is same across sub settings, but, a particular grouping may not be visible based on the setup type for a subsetting. So, ConfigurationA() combines all the operations for this group.

Answer (score 0):

> [Patterns](http://www.gofpatterns.com/design-patterns/module7/how-to-choose-designPattern.php)
>   are not the panacea of program design. They do not replace traditional
>   object-oriented analysis techniques like CRC cards or use-case
>   modeling. To use an architectural analogy, analysis lets you determine
>   that your house needs 200 amps of electricity. Patterns let you
>   determine how the wiring will be installed. Patterns do help you think
>   about the problems you may encounter while designing a system.
>   Therefore, a generic, pattern-based solution is often more robust than
>   a solution designed by one individual to solve a specific problem.
>   Given the number of design patterns in common use (as well as many
>   more being invented and discovered almost daily) it can sometimes be
>   hard to choose the pattern that suits your needs. The first thing you
>   should decide is whether the problem is fundamentally creational,
>   structural, or behavioral. Some problems, of course, have aspects of
>   two or even three, and may require you to mix and match patterns.

From [gofpatterns](http://www.gofpatterns.com/design-patterns/module7/how-to-choose-designPattern.php)

However having said that  I think the first part of your questions seems to be creational and the Builder pattern seems to be the closest match. I would use composition ( through interfaces) to set the  configurations as per the sub settings. Also the classes Configuration A and SubsettingsAC seem to be Base classes for Configuration and Subsetting   classes.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey I think comments are a better way to communicate to the poster than edits. However, I agree with the comment you left in the edit description. I added a reference to the page where this text can be found. (I googled it and found 2 places where as the 2nd cites from the one I linked)

Comment: thanks for the edit. I had added a hyperlink at the start of the quote. . guess this is more obvious.

Comment: You're right, I see it now. Glad I found the right source :-) Yes, methinks explitely mentioning the source before or after a citation is the proper way to cite a text.